# Pricing Model for Multiple Products

Tags: multiple-regression, predictive-models

Suppose that you have a group of products that are all competing against each other for sales, different cars at a dealership for example. You are trying to model the **percentage** of sales that each car will have, based on different price points. There is a great deal of correlation between a cars percent volume and it's price (lower the price and the volume goes up). This is also correlation between a cars volume and the price of other cars.

Multiple regression works here, but the sum of the percent volumes for all the cars should add to 1.

What would be the best way to model this scenario? If it's multiple regression, how can it be modified with the constraint that the sum of each cars volume should total 1?

Comment: Discrete choice models have been used a lot for modelling demand for cars. There is an extremely large econometric literature on this area.

Comment: [This](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2171802?seq=1) might be a good place to start if you are looking for what is typically done in the literature.